# C# how to mark the property of the abstract class is not null because setting is required in implementing class constructor (CS8618)?

Tags: c#, oop, nullable

I have an abstract class as a base class for various implementations.

Let it look like this:

```cs
public abstract class MyBase {

    public object Property1 { get; protected set; }

}
```

It is important, that the type of `Property1` is `object` and not `object?`.
I want it to be completely clear that the `Property1` is never null in implementation instance.

Let's say a typical implementation looks like this:

```cs
public sealed class MyImpl : MyBase {

    public MyImpl() {
        Property1 = new object();
    }

}
```

Of course in real world there are plenty of properties in the base class and they are of various types, not just `object`. I could mark the properties as `abstract`, but then I would have to implement them in each implementing class - that would mean more boilerplate code with no real benefit in that, right?

OK, but now I get a warning, that the properties must have non-null values before exiting constructor - CS8618. Of course I can disable the warning for my base class, but is there a more elegant way to instruct the compiler that the implementing class MUST set those properties to non-null values instead of disabling the warning?

It would be perfect if I get the warning not for the base class, but for the implementation if it doesn't set one of those properties.

As I already figured out - the latest C# compiler and Visual Studio has plenty of magic special attributes that change the nullable warning behavior, but I don't know where to look.

Comment: Your `abstract class`'s `Property1` should not have a `protected set`, instead it should have a `protected` constructor that requires the value as a parameter, otherwise there is no way to guarantee that the property will be set by a subclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is important, that the type of Property1 is object and not object?. I want it to be completely clear that the Property1 is never null in implementation instance.

The **only** way to guarantee that is with a `protected` constructor in `MyBase` that requires a value for `Property1` **or** by making `Property1` an `abstract` property.

In .NET, when a subclass is instantiated, first its supertype's constructor runs to completion, and then the constructor of the next child type, and so on. There is currently no provision in .NET for a supertype to have a "post-constructor" that runs after the most-derived-type's constructor runs (I wish there was though..), so there is no way for `MyBase` class to *prove to the compiler* that `Property1` will be in a valid state when the object is constructed. Having a `protected set` isn't any kind of provable guarantee (at least as far as the compiler is concerned): it's the OOP equivalent of a subclass saying "I pinkie-swear to set this property in my constructor!"  and the rest of your program has to *trust* that verbal promise.

This is why the nullable annotations since C# 8.0 are so important and so useful: because now we no-longer need to operate on mere trust: we can now have the compiler *actually verify* that a field/auto-property is actually assigned to a non-null value, thus preventing any `NullReferenceException` (*everyone's favourite kind of exception!*) from ever being thrown in the first place.

The fact the non-`abstract` subclass is `sealed` doesn't matter to the compiler in this case because your `MyBase` could still be derived separately by a misbehaving subclass that never sets `Property1`.

> Of course in real world there are plenty of properties in the base class and they are of various types, not just `object`. I could mark the properties as `abstract`, but then I would have to implement them in each implementing class - that would mean more boilerplate code with no real benefit in that, right?

I appreciate that having to copy+paste or manually keystroke-in repetitive members is annoying, but doing so is not "boilerplate" if (re)implementing those `abstract` members is expressing something meaningful in your business/domain model.

> I get a warning that the properties must have non-null values before exiting constructor - CS8618. Of course I can disable the warning for my base class, but is there a more elegant way to instruct the compiler that the implementing class MUST set those properties to non-null values instead of disabling the warning?

Just use a `protected` constructor. That's exactly what they're for.

Like this:

```
public abstract class MyBase
{
    protected MyBase(object property1Value)
    {
        this.Property1 = property1Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(property1Value));
    }

    public object Property1 { get; }

}
```

That way all subclasses will be safe:

```
public sealed class Derived : MyBase
{
    public Derived()
        : base( GetProperty1FromAStaticFactory() )
    {

    }
}
```

or

```
public sealed class Derived : MyBase
{
    public Derived( Object p1Value )
        : base( p1Value  )
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. To pass the data for the protected constructor I can use a record struct. The record syntax is succinct, overhead is small. Of course, I could just make the properties abstract... IDK. Both approaches seem OK.